# Android CoverFlow with Flipping effect as IOS coverflow

Tags: android, carousel, coverflow

Can someone suggest me of any CoverFlow example or library for Android which can achieve the same effect as [IOS CoverFlow](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oTXtO5KXalE) with cover flipping effect on selection. I have looked through a couple of android libraries and examples but none of them could achieve the effect which i needed, so if anyone of you have come across such library please suggest.Some of the Examples :

1. [Carousel Android](http://developer.digitalaria.com/devguide/gama/en/gama/carousel_android.php)
2. [Android Coverflow](https://code.google.com/p/android-coverflow/)

   Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [this library](http://code.google.com/p/android-coverflow/) for cover flow effect.